# How a variable takes value inside a function without declare it anywhere

Tags: python, lambda

I have a small python script where a variable inside a lambda function (which is inside another function) does not take any value from somewhere but still the script works and I can not understand why. Below I have my code, a is the mysterious variable. I know that for some reason it works but I don't know why.

```
 def myfunc(n):
   return lambda a : a * n <== a variable takes value from where???

 mydoubler = myfunc(2)
 print(mydoubler(11))
```

Comment: This is just ordinary vanilla lambda function behaviour

Answer (score 4):

You declared the variable here:

```
def myfunc(n):
   return lambda a : a * n
```

`a` is the name of the argument to the lambda

```
lambda a
```

This is equivalent to:

```
def some_name(a):
    ...
```

The only difference is that `lambda` is like a function with no name. Anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

Your `myfunc(n)` does not return a *value* it returns another function that has `n` according to whatever you called `myfunc` with and will - when executed - take *its* parameter `a` and multiply it by `n`:

```
def myfunc(n):
   return lambda a : a * n 

mydoubler = myfunc(2)
mytripler = myfunc(3)

print(type(mydoubler))  # <class 'function'> - n is set to 2
print(type(mytripler))  # <class 'function'> - n is set to 3

print(mydoubler(10)) # 20
print(mytripler(20)) # 60
```

You can even [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) your lambda and see what param it takes:

```
from inspect import signature

print(signature(mydoubler)) # (a)
print(signature(mytripler)) # (a)
```